# Why does Deutsch translate to German?

Tags: etymology

I mean, German comes from the fact that the Germans are Germanic (duh...) but the Germans aren't the only Germanic people out there... So, the meaning of Deutsch must not be "German" per se, or is it?

If it is, then Germany is like the origin of the Germanic people?

Comment: Shouldn't that be asked in http://english.stackexchange.com? It is about the *English* translation of "Deutsch", isn't it?

Comment: @tofro, yes duplicate! Thank's for finding it (believe me I looked). `:)`

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, It's not about the *translation*, it's more about the *meaning* of Deutsch. It does not mean Germanic, does it? (it's specified in the question) Though it's a duplicate, the linked question has a very nice answer.

Comment: Concerning its age-long history, the *best* name is “Deutschland”. It’s not the land of the Germanic, nor the Alemanni, Foreigners or Saxons, but [*The Land of the People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodiscus). Study the [**names of Germany**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany) for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Neither does "German" :-) That's why they are two distinct words: German and Germanic.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/polandball/comments/2050ui/how_are_they_called/